# How can I stop Google App Engine(GAE) from CloudFunctions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to stop GAE instance from CloudFunctions(node.js 8)

I refered to the following documents.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta5/apps.services.versions/patch?hl=JA

I wrote below code

```
        var requestdata = {
            appsId: PROJECT_NAME,
            servicesId: SERVICE_ID,
            versionsId: VERSION_ID,
            auth: authClient,
            automaticScaling: {
                standardSchedulerSettings:
              {
                maxInstances: 0,
                minInstances: 0
              }
            },  
        }
        appengine.apps.services.versions.patch(requestdata);
```

But it is not work well.
I encounter this error message.

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "automaticScaling[standardSchedulerSettings][maxInstances]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'automaticScaling[standardSchedulerSettings][maxInstances]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "automaticScaling[standardSchedulerSettings][minInstances]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'automaticScaling[standardSchedulerSettings][minInstances]' could not be found in request message.
```

I do not know how to solve the problem.
If you have any advice, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not expert in Javascript, but it seems you're are passing a Javascript object instead of JSON. If that's the case, you need to convert it to JSON using `JSON.stringify(requestdata)` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `standardSchedulerSettings` is not a valid parameter as it does not exist in v1beta5.

As of [January 2019](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/upgrading-to-latest-release), the Admin API was upgraded from v1beta -> V1.

> The v1beta4 and v1beta5 versions of the API are no longer supported and scheduled for shut down on January 14, 2019.

To resolve this just update any old dependencies you may have to the latest [version](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/appengine/v1/java/latest/) and make sure to follow the latest V1 apps.services.versions.patch [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch?) .

This worked for me.